# Simulate TDBNavigator Button Click

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

To simulate a `TButton` click we would use:

```
Button1.Click
```

But how do we apply something similar for the `TDBNavigator`?
Say for example, I want simulate the Refresh button of the `TDBNavigator` inside my code. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you use a button click? Why not call `Refresh` on the data set?

Comment: It didn't occur to me, but thank you David :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you are asking for `TDBNavigator`:

```
DBNavigator.BtnClick(nbRefresh);
```